# Having permission problems while trying to create pdf file on Apache Server using Django

Tags: python, django, apache

I have a problem with deployment of my web app.

I am using Django 2.1.7 on apache2.

I set all the proper permissions to folders and files (at least thats what I think):

```sh
drwxr-s--- 10 bedirt www-data 4096 Mar  8 21:10 projectNal
```

And in the folder:

```sh
-rwxr-x---  1 bedirt www-data  11357 Mar  2 20:37 LICENSE
-rwxr-x---  1 bedirt www-data     12 Mar  2 20:37 README.md
drwxr-x---  4 bedirt www-data   4096 Mar  2 20:42 addQuestion
-rwxrwx---  1 bedirt www-data 536576 Mar  2 21:51 db.sqlite3
-rwxr-x---  1 bedirt www-data    542 Mar  2 20:37 manage.py
drwxrwx---  2 bedirt www-data   4096 Mar  8 21:10 media
drwxr-x---  3 bedirt www-data   4096 Mar  8 21:53 projectNal
drwxr-x---  6 bedirt www-data   4096 Mar  8 22:49 qBank
-rwxr-x---  1 bedirt www-data    512 Mar  2 20:37 requirements.txt
drwxr-x--- 12 bedirt www-data   4096 Mar  2 20:37 static
drwxr-x---  5 bedirt www-data   4096 Mar  2 20:37 users
drwxr-x---  5 bedirt www-data   4096 Mar  2 20:37 venv
```

I am using **pylatex** to create a latex document, the procedure is - it runs latex compilation and removes the .tex file, and uploads the pdf on media folder.

Here is the code:

### Output_tex.py

```py
def create_worksheet_pdf(data, title):

    # Document with `\maketitle` command activated
    doc = Document(default_filepath='../media/', documentclass='exam')
    # Title part

    doc.preamble.append(Command('headrule'))
    doc.preamble.append(Command('chead', '?'))
    doc.preamble.append(Command('lhead', '?'))
    doc.preamble.append(Command('rhead', '?'))

    # questions
    with doc.create(Section(title)):
        doc.append(Command('begin', 'questions'))
        for row in data:
            questionHead = r'\question (' + row.year + '-' + row.source + '-' + row.problemNumber + ')\\\\'
            doc.append(NoEscape(questionHead))
            doc.append(NoEscape(r"" + row.problemStatement))    
        doc.append(Command('end', 'questions'))
    # questions end

    # end
    doc.generate_pdf(filepath='media/'+title, clean_tex=True)
```

The `filepath` parts might be important in this file, so I couldn't use MEDIA_ROOT or MEDIA_URL since I get error. As can be seen on the permission I gave write access to apache (www-data) for both media and the db. My media files etc works fine on local, but I just uploaded to server and now i cant figure out why it is not working.

**The error is:**

```
PermissionError at /output/
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Momentum-Questions.tex'
```

And I did configure `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL`, here it is:

## Settings.py

```py
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

- Everything was working fine up until I added the craeting pdf part. So My conf file and stuff are fine, if there is nothing else is needs to added.

Comment: Even if I give full permission and ownership to www-data I still get the same error...

Comment: Use absolute paths bases on the constants from the settings: `os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, title)`

Comment: maan thats it :) thank you @KlausD.